# Will a pink ward reveal Akali's location, even if the ward isn't inside the Twilight Shroud?

Tags: league-of-legends

So if I place a pink ward near the `twilight shroud` (not inside of it), will it still reveal Akali's location?

Comment: Purple? I always hear them be called "pinks"

Comment: They are salmon

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The ward provide magical vision with a range of 1000.
It will reveal any stealth champion within this range unless they are in a bush and the ward itself is not. Akali's shroud is not a bush, so it does not block the magical sighting.

Regarding Akali's shroud, it might be best to keep the ward in your inventory and be quick enough to pop it into her shroud when she pops (if you can kill her). This strategy provides three main advantages: gold efficiency (use the ward only if necessary), surprise effect (Akali might not be as reactive as you are, thinking the stealth is protecting her) and better precision (otherwise she might use her far from your ward).

Answer (score 3):

The ward does not need to be inside the shroud, it only needs to be close enough to Akali's location. Likewise for a champion bearing the Oracle's Elixir buff.

Comment: Similarly, a purple ward can reveal another ward inside a brush, even if it is not itsself inside the brush.

Comment: @Lawton a vision ward can't reveal a ward that's inside a brush unless the ward itself is inside the brush. The borders of a brush act as a one-way mirror, vision-wise; things can see out, but nothing can see in.

Comment: @Sconibulus I believe the ward in the bush gets visible when you walk in the bush yourself. But I might be mistaken.

Comment: I was referring to that Joetjah said, yes. Basically vision is a separate mechanic from "true sight", and so it goes through brush and stuff so when you get vision of that brush the wards will show up.

Comment: I know it's true about what Joetjah said. But I thought that you could see the ward, only if you place the pink in the same brush, and not outside of it. When I used oracle, I went into the brush and found the ward. (Correct me if I'm wrong but..) the pink ward didn't.